# Magento2: Adding a block to referenceContainer on all pages?

Tags: magento2, blocks, magento-2.1

I'm trying to get a block to embed on all pages. I've tried many references containers including `footer`, `page.top` and `page.wrapper`. The only one I've managed to get to include correctly on the `thankyou (order success)` page in `footer`.

Even using `footer` the embed does not seem to happen on category or CMS pages. I'm using the default Magento 2 theme and test data.

My `default.xml` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head> </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Company\Module\Block\Module" name="company_module" template="Company_Module::tracking.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: How about your issue? I updated my answer.

Answer (score 6):

**The footer and header are removed in the checkout page**. So, when we try to reference these blocks, our block will be removed also.
We can follow the logic of the copyright. Try to move your element outside the footer - `<move element="company_module" destination="before.body.end"/>`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="footer">
        <block class='Company\Module\Block\Module' name="company_module" as="company_module" template="Company_Module::tracking.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    <move element="company_module" destination="before.body.end"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Or we can reference to `before.body.end` or `after.body.start` container:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
        <block class='Company\Module\Block\Module' name="company_module" as="company_module" after="footer_links" template="Company_Module::tracking.phtml"/>
     </referenceContainer>
     <!--<referenceContainer name="after.body.start">-->
        <!--<block class='Company\Module\Block\Module' name="company_module" as="company_module" after="footer_links" template="Company_Module::tracking.phtml"/>-->
    <!--</referenceContainer>-->
   </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried both, but neither actually worked to get my template embedded in category pages. By category page I mean those pages such as http://magento2.dev/women/tops-women.html in the sample data.

Comment: You're using a custom theme? All the footer content will miss in the category page? I'm pretty sure that if we reference to `before.body.end` container, our block still show. Please, check again.

Comment: Sadly, no it's not a custom theme. This is the default theme that comes with the "sample data" Magento 2.0 CC. Neither setting "before.body.end", nor trying the move operator seems to work. I'm sure I must be missing some kind of caching or such problems ...

Comment: I've been looking at this problem again. Any help? This is the default theme, LUMA. Won't show on category pages with "footer" or "before.body.end". :(

Answer (score 3):

You can try this code, working fine for me

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
    <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Test\Test" after="footer_links" template="Vendor_Module::test/test.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks, although I have tried the direct footer as you suggest and there are pages missing.