# Add google tag manager code inside head and body

Tags: magento2, head, google-tag-manager

I have a question regarding magento. I would like to know where the head and body are located. I want to do this because i would like to add a Google tag manager code inside it. I can somehow not seem to find where it is located.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your Magento version please

Comment: @Prince  magento 2

Comment: and how do i add the javascript file in them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add JS files like this:

duplicate the file:

```
app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
```

to

```
app/code/*your_vendor*/*your_theme*/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
```

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <!-- Add local resources -->
        <css src="css/my-styles.css"/>

        <!-- The following two ways to add local JavaScript files are equal -->
        <script src="Magento_Catalog::js/sample1.js"/>
        <link src="js/sample.js"/>

        <!-- Add external resources -->
        <css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" src_type="url" />
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" src_type="url" />
        <link src="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" src_type="url" /> 
    </head>
</page>
```

for more informtation:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html

**EDIT:**

To add block in content to all pages:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/139772/48355

Comment: what do i do if i want to add something in the body

Comment: Please, look my answer.

Answer (score 8):

The basic GTM code can be added easily using the following three steps -:

**Step 1**

> gtm_head.phtml ---> YourTheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/gtm_head.phtml

**add the following script:**

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

**Step 2**

> gtm_body.phtml ---> YourTheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/gtm_body.phtml

**add the following script:**

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

**Step 3**

> default .xml file: --->YourTheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
>   and add this:

```
<referenceContainer name="head.additional">
 <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="gtm.head" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/gtm_head.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>

<referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
 <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="gtm.body" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/gtm_body.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

The above will add basic script of GTM code on your Magento 2 store but GTM is all about data and data layers without them there is very little can be done using the basic script of GTM.

For example - for Google Enhanced Ecommerce, you need to create data layers for all the below actions / pages

- Product Impressions (for category, up-sell, cross-sell and search results) - Wherever you are showing list of products.
- Product Clicks (for category, up-sell, cross-sell and search results) - Wherever you are showing list of products.
- Product Detail Impressions (for product detail page)
- Add / Remove from Cart (for add to cart or remove from cart action)
- Promotion Impressions (for list of banners / ads)
- Promotion Clicks (for click of the banner / ad image)
- Checkout (for checkout / checkout steps)
- Purchases (for order confirmation page)
- Refunds (from admin to send refund to GA in case of refunds)

If you are a developer you can add the above data layers in your code using the following layout handlers -:

- default.xml
- catalog_category_view.xml
- catalog_product_view.xml
- catalogsearch_advanced_result.xml
- catalogsearch_result_index.xml
- checkout_cart_index.xml
- checkout_index_index.xml
- checkout_onepage_success.xml

If not then there are quite few extensions available for small amount to buy. Personally I would recommend the following two extension for M1 and M2

[M1 Google Tag Manager with Enhanced Ecommerce](https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-google-tag-manager-enhanced-ecommerce-tracking.html)

[M2 Google Tag Manager with Enhanced Ecommerce](https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-2-google-tag-manager-enhanced-ecommerce-tracking.html)

source -: [How to pass data in Data layer in magento 2.1 - Google tag Manager / Analytics](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/231011/how-to-pass-data-in-data-layer-in-magento-2-1-google-tag-manager-analytics/259404#259404)

Answer (score 1):

I would also note that Magento 2 Enterprise Edition has some built in support for GTM:

http://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/marketing/google-tag-manager.html

This is also a relevant StackExchange question you might enjoy if you need to implement it yourself in CE:

[Add Google Tag Manager to Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116943/add-google-tag-manager-to-magento-2)

Answer (score 0):

While you can successfully add your Google Analytics script by placing it in default_head_blocks.xml, you can also just add your GA ID from Magento Admin.

**Stores > Configuration > Sales > Google API**

Then, from your GA admin panel you should go to E-commerce Settings and
enable E-commerce and turn on Enhanced E-commerce Reporting.

*That's for Magento 2.1

Answer (score 0):

- Try this Code google_tag_param Category, Pagetype and product price wise.

  ```
  <?php
  /**
   * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
   * See COPYING.txt for license details.
   */

  /**
   * @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo $block
   */
  ?>
  <script src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl("js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"); ?>"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl("js/menumaker.js"); ?>"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl("js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"); ?>"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl("css/menumaker.css"); ?>" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl("css/jquery.bxslider.css"); ?>" />
  <?php 
      $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
      $request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context')->getRequest();
      $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category
      $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product



      $category_urlkey = "";
      $pagetype = "";
      $product_price = "";

      if ($request->getFullActionName() == 'cms_index_index') {
          $category_urlkey = "index";
          $pagetype = "home" ;
      }
      else if($product){
          //echo $category->getId();
          //echo $category->getName();
          $category_urlkey = $product->getSku();
          $pagetype = "product" ;
          $product_price = $product->getFinalPrice();
      }else if($category){

          $category_urlkey = $category->getUrlKey();
          $pagetype = "category" ;

      }

   ?>
     <script type="text/javascript"> 
         var google_tag_params = { 
         ecomm_prodid: <?php echo $category_urlkey; ?>, 
         ecomm_pagetype: <?php echo $pagetype; ?>, 
         ecomm_totalvalue: <?php echo $product_price; ?> 
      }; 
     </script>


  <?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('head-top')->toHtml();?>
  <?php $storeName = $block->getThemeName() ? $block->getThemeName() : $block->getLogoAlt();?>
  <span data-action="toggle-nav" class="action nav-toggle"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Toggle Nav') ?></span></span>
  <?php if ($block->isHomePage()):?>
      <strong class="logo">
  <?php else: ?>
      <a class="logo" href="<?php echo $block->getUrl(''); ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $storeName ?>">
  <?php endif ?>
          <img src="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getLogoSrc() ?>"
               alt="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getLogoAlt() ?>"
               <?php echo $block->getLogoWidth() ? 'width="' . $block->getLogoWidth() . '"' : '' ?>
               <?php echo $block->getLogoHeight() ? 'height="' . $block->getLogoHeight() . '"' : '' ?>
          />
  <?php if ($block->isHomePage()):?>
      </strong>
  <?php else:?>
      </a>
  <?php endif?>
  ```

Please check screen short

[image]