# How to pass data in Data layer in magento 2.1 - Google tag Manager / Analytics

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I've created **google analytics** and **Google tag manager** account to find out all event of product like `Add to Cart`, `Remove Cart`, `Checkout`, `Product click`, Checkout, `Product impression` in Google Analytics.

I've created tag and Trgger for that but its not reflecting in Google anaytics.

First i want to display data layer in front end with all products details.

Please tell me how to pass data in data layer.

So i have to put code in core file to get `product id`, `name`, `price`, etc. and pass variable on datapush script as mentioned on this [**URL.**](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce)

Or Magento have default functionality for this. 
only paste the script on header file? to get **datalayer** in frontend with details

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the Google Tag Manager module I would recommend for Magento 2 -:

https://github.com/magepal/magento2-google-tag-manager

Comment: Event Category and Label not reflecting in Google Analytics

Comment: I installed this plugin but addToCArt, removeFromCart is not reflecting in Google Analytics. What am I missing here? I have also defined Google Analytics from Magento -> Sales -> Google API. I am not sure what am I missing here? I can see transaction data in Google Analytics but could not see add to cart and cart abandoned data

Comment: This is not an answer

Answer (score 4):

The basic GTM code can be added easily using the following three steps -:

**Step 1**

> gtm_head.phtml ---> YourTheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/gtm_head.phtml

**add the following script:**

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

**Step 2**

> gtm_body.phtml ---> YourTheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/gtm_body.phtml

**add the following script:**

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

**Step 3**

> default .xml file: --->YourTheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
>   and add this:

```
<referenceContainer name="head.additional">
 <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="gtm.head" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/gtm_head.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>

<referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
 <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="gtm.body" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/gtm_body.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

The above will add basic script of GTM code on your Magento 2 store but GTM is all about data and data layers without them there is very little can be done using the basic script of GTM.

For example - for Google Enhanced Ecommerce, you need to create data layers for all the below actions / pages

- Product Impressions (for category, up-sell, cross-sell and search results) - Wherever you are showing list of products. https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#product-impressions
- Product Clicks (for category, up-sell, cross-sell and search results) - Wherever you are showing list of products. https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#product-clicks
- Product Detail Impressions (for product detail page) https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#details
- Add / Remove from Cart (for add to cart or remove from cart action) https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#cart
- Promotion Impressions (for list of banners / ads) https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#promo-impressions
- Promotion Clicks (for click of the banner / ad image) https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#promo-clicks
- Checkout (for checkout / checkout steps) https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#checkout
- Purchases (for order confirmation page) https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases
- Refunds (from admin to send refund to GA in case of refunds) https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#refunds

If you are a developer you can add the above data layers in your code using the following layout handlers -:

- default.xml
- catalog_category_view.xml
- catalog_product_view.xml
- catalogsearch_advanced_result.xml
- catalogsearch_result_index.xml
- checkout_cart_index.xml
- checkout_index_index.xml
- checkout_onepage_success.xml

If not then there are quite few extensions available for small amount to buy. Personally I would recommend the following two extension for M1 and M2

[M1 Google Tag Manager with Enhanced Ecommerce](https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-google-tag-manager-enhanced-ecommerce-tracking.html)

[M2 Google Tag Manager with Enhanced Ecommerce](https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-2-google-tag-manager-enhanced-ecommerce-tracking.html)

Answer (score -1):

This issue was a real pain. But finally able to resolve this issue by using [this plugin](https://www.weltpixel.com/google-analytics-enhanced-ecommerce-tag-manager-magento-2.html) (Free Version)

This provide some additional data for Google Analytics and will resolve your problems! Enjoy :)