# How to install Google TAG Manager in magento 1.9

Tags: google, google-tag-manager

How to install Google TAG Manager (GTM) to Magento 1.9.2 without extension?

[image]

Comment: It could be difficult without the **FREE** extension provided by google. What the reason for you to choose not to use it?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/magepal/magento1-google-tag-manager

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to use the extension. By doing it, you can pass a number of useful data, like product ID to the tag manager.

However, there is a way of installing Google Tag Manager without extension. Just follow these steps:

1. First, create a static block containing the script (CMS > Static
   Blocks).
2. Deactivate WYSWIWYG editor.
3. Then enter JavaScript ("Hide Editor").
4. Now, you have to create a new widget instance (CMS > Widgets).
5. Choose your theme.
6. Add layout update for "All pages."
7. Use "Page Top" as the reference.
8. Choose static block from (1) in "Widget Options."
9. Finally, save the changes and clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

The basic GTM code can be added easily using the following three steps -:

**Step 1**

> gtm_head.phtml ---> YourTheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/gtm_head.phtml

**add the following script:**

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

**Step 2**

> gtm_body.phtml ---> YourTheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/gtm_body.phtml

**add the following script:**

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

**Step 3**

> default .xml file: --->YourTheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
>   and add this:

```
<referenceContainer name="head.additional">
 <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="gtm.head" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/gtm_head.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>

<referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
 <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="gtm.body" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/gtm_body.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

The above will add basic script of GTM code on your Magento 2 store but GTM is all about data and data layers without them there is very little can be done using the basic script of GTM.

For example - for Google Enhanced Ecommerce, you need to create data layers for all the below actions / pages

- Product Impressions (for category, up-sell, cross-sell and search results) - Wherever you are showing list of products.
- Product Clicks (for category, up-sell, cross-sell and search results) - Wherever you are showing list of products.
- Product Detail Impressions (for product detail page)
- Add / Remove from Cart (for add to cart or remove from cart action)
- Promotion Impressions (for list of banners / ads)
- Promotion Clicks (for click of the banner / ad image)
- Checkout (for checkout / checkout steps)
- Purchases (for order confirmation page)
- Refunds (from admin to send refund to GA in case of refunds)

If you are a developer you can add the above data layers in your code using the following layout handlers -:

- default.xml
- catalog_category_view.xml
- catalog_product_view.xml
- catalogsearch_advanced_result.xml
- catalogsearch_result_index.xml
- checkout_cart_index.xml
- checkout_index_index.xml
- checkout_onepage_success.xml

Google has given a wonderful code snippets for each page for you to implement by yourself. Just make sure you create exact data layers as specified by Google in their following documentation -:

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce

If not then there are quite few extensions available for small amount to buy. Personally I would recommend the following two extension for M1 and M2

[M1 Google Tag Manager with Enhanced Ecommerce](https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-google-tag-manager-enhanced-ecommerce-tracking.html)

[M2 Google Tag Manager with Enhanced Ecommerce](https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-2-google-tag-manager-enhanced-ecommerce-tracking.html)

source -: [How to pass data in Data layer in magento 2.1 - Google tag Manager / Analytics](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/231011/how-to-pass-data-in-data-layer-in-magento-2-1-google-tag-manager-analytics/259404#259404)